# What does 愛されて mean in this song

Tags: て-form, passive-form

I was reading a lyric of a song from an anime called bocchi the rock and there was a line that I didn't really understand what it means

> いいな 君は みんなから愛されて
> 「いいや 僕は ずっと一人きりさ」

What does 愛されて here actually means. I know that it is a passive + te form of the 愛す but I don't know how it functions.

I did search the internet for the translated version of the lyrics but I find two possible translation for that line

> Must be nice, to be loved by everyone.
> “No such thing, I have always been alone”

and

> How lucky would it be, for everyone to have loved you.
> "The thing is, I've really been all alone this whole time."

So I really don't know which is the correct translation for 愛されて in this context.

Comment: Either way, "you" are loved by everyone. Which part is not clear to you?

Comment: @aguijonazo the first translation I understand it as the person in question is being loved by everyone while the second translation I understand it as the the singer wants the person in question to be loved by everyone. This part is the one that is confusing to me

Answer (score 2):

It's part of a longer sentence. The sentence, in a more "prosaic" word order, is:

> 君はみんなから愛されて、いいな。
>
> How wonderful it is that you're loved by everyone!
> You're loved by everyone, and/so I envy you!

Here, 愛されて is functioning as the reason for the corresponding predicate (いいな). In other words, it's the [te-form (て-form) for Cause or Reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html).

Also note that いいな, いいなぁ and so on often express the feeling of envy.

Comment: Huh, I never knew that the te form for cause or reason can be use this way. I always thought that for this usage, the te form verb must be placed before the consequence of the cause or reason

Comment: @asyrafshaari In an ordinary prose, yes you're correct, but [倒置](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E5%80%92%E7%BD%AE) is very common in poems and lyrics.